# Get Likedby column value from List Rating Setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, custom-list, rating, webapi

I have created a custom list and activated rating setting.

I want to count the number of `likes` and `likedby`. But when I modify the list view I found `Likedby` is disable but checked and `likedby` is not listed in

```
siteurl /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SampleList()
```

or

```
siteurl/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('SampleList')/items()
```

Please help me to find the `likedby` in SharePoint Online.

Comment: you did not give any response to my answer

Answer (score 3):

`LikedBy` is a multi valued lookup column. You have to `$expand` it in the query. Just make `GET` request to the following end-point, in response you will get LikesCount and LikedBy

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items?$select=LikesCount,LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy
```

Above query will give you the Title of `LikedBy` user as I am using `LikedBy/Title` in `$select` like following

```
    {
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "f2592d31-7960-42c1-a51b-b0cbf6238483",
          "uri": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'ba8a6814-61cd-4dc6-92f2-ae088316744a')/Items(1)",
          "etag": "\"2\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.Short_x0020_DescriptionListItem"
        },
        "LikedBy": {
          "results": [
            {
              "__metadata": {
                "id": "e81c95c7-b0f0-44ff-aa46-71d6a7782bc8",
                "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
              },
              "Title": "Mohammad Mazumder"
            }
          ]
        },
        "LikesCount": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you need more fields of `LikedBy` user, then mention them in the `$select` like following.

```
$select=LikesCount,LikedBy/Id,LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy
```

If you have time, have a look on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API) article.

Answer (score 0):

I did something quite similar in SharePoint 2013 on-prem. You can check my step-by-step guide [here](https://afrait.com/blog/like-list-items-facebook-like-en). Maybe there are some useful information.

Also here a code snippet I used:

```
var listId = 'E7585AC3-82C5-4D02-A9E9-58A735DB89B9';
var siteUrl = '/';
var itemId = 1;

    function GetLikeCount(j) {

        //alert("Run for Item ID: " + j);  
        var passedItemId = j;
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
        var item = list.getItemById(passedItemId);

        context.load(item, "LikedBy", "ID", "LikesCount");
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (success) {

            //Check if the user id of the current users is in the collection LikedBy. 
            var likeDisplay = true;
            var $v_0 = item.get_item('LikedBy');
            var itemc = item.get_item('LikesCount');

            //alert(itemc);
            if (!SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined($v_0)) {
                for (var $v_1 = 0, $v_2 = $v_0.length; $v_1 < $v_2; $v_1++){
                    var $v_3 = $v_0[$v_1];
                    if ($v_3.$1E_1 === _spPageContextInfo.userId) {
                        //cb(true, item.get_item('LikesCount'));

                        //alert("Liked by me");
                        likeDisplay = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            ChangeLikeText(likeDisplay, itemc, passedItemId);

        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            //alert('F1');
        }));

    }
```

If you have some questions, don't be afraIT to ask.