# How to send a "like" or "unlike" command via REST API?

Tags: rest, rating, like, api

The structure of my REST-API Url is `/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('FAQ')/Items`.

Each item can be liked by users (like in discussion boards).

How can I send a "Like" or "Unlike" command via REST?

Comment: Maybe you can check those links: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163301/… or directly a guide I wrote here: https://afrait.com/blog/like-list-items-facebook-like-en or a question asked here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160912/get-likedby-column-value-from-list-rating-setting/160913#160913

Answer (score 8):

Do you use Javascript to send "Like"? At this case you could use JSOM to set likes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

SP.SOD.registerSod('reputation.js', '/_layouts/15/reputation.js');
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('reputation.js', 'Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation', function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', UpdateLike);
});

function UpdateLike() {
    var itemId = 1;
    var listId = "361d6bc5-0034-4f53-8f7b-f7198a3a844c";//set list id
    var setLike = true;//set false to unlike

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("siteUrl");//your site url
    Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike(ctx, listId, itemId, setLike);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.RatingSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.RatingFailure));
};

function RatingSuccess(sender, args) {
    alert('Rating Done Successfully');
}

function RatingFailure(sender, args) {
    alert('SetRating failed:' + args.get_message());//note that you will get error if try like twice
}
</script>
```

That is not well documented. I could not find is it available by REST or not.

Comment: Ooh this looks nice. I'll try it out and come back to you, thanks !

Comment: @MonsieurPoivron, how is it going? Do you need any help with solution?

Comment: this works .. thannks.

Comment: this works ... thanks. One question  - by OOTB functionality when you clink on  Like/Unlike, it does not update the item but by the above code item gets updated. Is other anything we can do to do not update the item

Answer (score 5):

The below example demonstrates how to like/unlike a resource via SharePoint REST API, it simulates `Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike` method to some extent

> Prerequisites: `Rating settings` needs to be enabled per List

```
var Reputation = Reputation || {};

Reputation = (function () {

    function executeJson(options) {
        var headers = options.headers || {};
        headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        if (options.method == "POST") {
            headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
        }

        var ajaxOptions =
            {
                url: options.url,
                type: options.method,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: headers
            };
        if (options.method == "POST") {
            ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.payload);
        }

        return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    }

    function getListItem(webUrl, listTitle, itemId) {
        var options = {
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")",
            method: "GET"
        };
        return executeJson(options);
    }

    function updateListItem(webUrl, listTitle, itemId, itemPayload) {
        var options = {
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            payload: itemPayload
        };
        return executeJson(options);
    }



    return {
        setLike: function (webUrl, listTitle, itemId, setLike) {
            //1.retieve existing ratings
            return getListItem(webUrl, listTitle, itemId)
                .then(function (data) {
                    //2.set like for current user
                    var userKey = _spPageContextInfo.userId.toString();
                    var likes = data.d.LikesCount;
                    var updated = false;
                    var userKeys = data.d.LikedByStringId == null ?  [] : data.d.LikedByStringId.results;
                    var posKey = userKeys.indexOf(userKey);
                    if (posKey == -1) {
                        if (setLike) {
                            userKeys.push(userKey);
                            likes++;
                            updated = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (!setLike) {
                            userKeys.splice(posKey, 1);
                            likes--;
                            updated = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (updated) {
                        var itemProperties = {
                            "__metadata": data.d.__metadata,
                            "LikedByStringId": {"results": userKeys},
                            LikesCount: likes
                        };
                        return updateListItem(webUrl, listTitle, itemId, itemProperties);
                    }
                    return data;

                });
        }
    };
})();
```

Gist: [setLike.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/cdaaf82007b7bbb266da377b5d2a2f29)

**Usages**

- *like* a resource: `Reputation.setLike(webUrl, listTitle, itemId,
  true)`
- *unlike* a resource: `Reputation.setLike(webUrl, listTitle, itemId, false)`

**Example**

```
var listTitle = "Feedback";
var itemId = 1;
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

Reputation.setLike(webUrl, listTitle, itemId, true)
    .done(function (item) {
        console.log('Liked');
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```