# how to set like/Unlike in document library using SPfx

Tags: spfx

Using SharePoint Frame work, I am displaying the image and below it has like button and comments section. When I hit the like button of the particular item image , it should update in the document library.

Kindly do the needful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to call [`Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj884385%28v=office.15%29) using `CSOM`.

There is a [dicussion here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167912/how-to-send-a-like-or-unlike-command-via-rest-api) that might help you.

Comment: Error throws cannot find name 'SP'.ts

Comment: You need make sure SP.js is loaded... Have you read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom ?