# How to get multiple users with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm developing one Like functionality for users. Iam getting userId by using following code but how can i get multiple users using REST API because i want to then compare with current user if its already liked article then i dont want to allow that user to like .Any help would be appreciatable.

```
function getUserId() {

var requestUri = AppWebUrl+ "/_api/web/currentUser";
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(AppWebUrl);
executor.executeAsync({
    url: requestUri,
    Method: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: console.log(userid),
    error: onError
});
}
```

Comment: so where are the likes stored? There should be a way to tell share point to get the other user right? Whats the criteria?

Comment: Maybe you can check those links: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163301/formating-list-with-jslink-like-button or directly a guide I wrote here: https://afrait.com/blog/like-list-items-facebook-like-en/ or a question asked here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160912/get-likedby-column-value-from-list-rating-setting/160913#160913

Comment: i have custom list where i have articleTite string field . user field and one like column to store likes by user .

Comment: get all users in site:  **/_api/web/siteUsers**