# How to Get Likedby column value

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, managed-metadata

[image]

When users hover over the like column, they can see all the likers (users who liked the item.)

I wonder where does SharePoint store those information "likedby", and how can I retrieve it? For example, if I added the like column to a document library, how can I see a list of all the documents I have liked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Enable ratings in your document library. ( List/Library Settings > Rating Settings)

[image]

2) `LikedBy` is the column which stores the users who have liked list items.

After that you can use the below REST api to get all like by users:

```
https://sitecollectionurl/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('CustomDocLib')/items?$select=Title,LikedBy/Title,LikedBy/ID&$expand=LikedBy
```

Here `LikedBy` is OOTB column which is enabled after ratings is activated in the library.

Comment: What is "$expand=LikedBy" means? If we can retrieve via REST, does it mean I can get the data from Search? Because I can't find any managed property, can't get "LikedBy" from search tool either

Comment: It just says The field or property 'LikedBy' does not exist

Comment: LikedBy is a multi valued lookup column. So u need to use $expand it in the query.  The error looks strange. Did you enable the ratings as i have in the screenshot ?

Comment: I enable the rating in the very first step, that's how I get the screenshot. I found another REST api actually works. Just slightly different from this answer

Comment: It's the same endpoint. This answer is "$select=Title,LikedBy" but my site couldn't find LikedBy at that time. Another answer is "$select=LikesCount,LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy" which enable me to get what I want

Comment: As LikedBy is a lookup field, so it can't be use as `$select=LikedBy`. You need to specify ID or Title to fetch the value of Lookup field and need to expand it for fetching its value. Proper way to use lookup field like LikedBy is `$select=LikedBy/ID,LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy`.

Comment: have used it the same way :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160912/get-likedby-column-value-from-list-rating-setting) actually works for me after researching a while:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items?$select=LikesCount,LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy
```

This SP CRUD Operation [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/990131/crud-operation-to-list-using-sharepoint-rest-api) helps a lot.